# QSqlQueryModel for ListView usage

Tags: sql, qt, listview, qml

I have a simple class

```
class SqlContactModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SqlContactModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addContact( const QString& contactName );
    Q_INVOKABLE void removeContact( const QString& contactName );
};
```

to be used inside ListView as a model like

```
model : SqlContactModel{}
```

and it works fine if I set a text property of my delegate as

```
contactId: model.display
```

The question is - why does it work? This example is provided by http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-chattutorial-example.html but there is no explanation to this `model.display` property. I can't see `display` anywhere inside QSqlQueryModel or ListView.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: May be [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) link can help you.

Comment: Great - this is what I was looking for !!!

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlQueryModel` inherits from `QAbstractTableModel` which inherits from `QAbstractItemModel`.

It's documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) that the default roles of a QAbstractItemModel subclass are exposed to QML as attached properties.

Qt Role: `Qt::DisplayRole` -> QML Role Name: `display`